# Xamarin horizontal collection view - how to expand children to fill full available width

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a simple collection view in Xamarin with horizontal orientation
[collection view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmmV9.png)

Is there any possibility to make them fill full available space, so if there are only two, each will have 50% width? I can't set the width to be fixed, since the number of items is dynamic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe that you will need to dynamically calculate the size of the cell

Comment: Add Grid columns in code?

Comment: BindableLayout Stacklayout with Horizontal orientation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this please in the collectionview

```
<CollectionView ItemsLayout="HorizontalGrid, 2">
```

try changing the integer value till it fits you.